# BASH - How to replace only one tag in an XML, when duplicates appear?

Tags: xml, bash, tags, replace, duplicates

Here is how my xml file looks like:

```
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <version>5.1.3-SNAPSHOT</version>

<parent>
    <artifactId>xxx</artifactId>
    <groupId>group</groupId>
    <version>5.1.3-SNAPSHOT</version>
</parent>

<artifactId>yyy</artifactId>
<packaging>pom</packaging>
<name>artifact name</name>

<modules>           
    <module>m1</module>
    <module>m2</module>
    <module>m3</module>
</modules>
```

I want to delete the "-SNAPSHOT" string ONLY from the  tag within <parent>.

How do I do that?

Answer (score 1):

This is past the capabilities of simple line-based approaches. You might use sed magic with line selection operators or do perl.

An example in sed would be (but just for educational purposes! Don't try this at home! This script is pretty unstable towards changes in the XML):

```
/<parent>/,/<.parent>/s/-SNAPSHOT//
```

However, XSLT and `xsltproc` is definitely the preferred solution for such heavy XML-processing duties.

Comment: I tried using sed, but did nod find a way to do this. Could you point me to some helpful example?

Comment: Sorry, can't do that, because people try to avoid that voodoo and not publish it if they did :-). Edited the answer with an example.